# overlay post title over post's featured image

Tags: theme-development, css

I'm using the Twenty Seventeen Wordpress Theme. I'm trying to do something similar to the below image for the static front page:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Currently, this is an image of what I have on my site:

[image]
The post title is currently on the bottom of the image.  I would like it to be on the image as seen in the above image.

Right now in my code, I have the default code from Twenty Seventeen theme's `content-front-page.php` populating the the post thread. Below:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'twentyseventeen-panel ' ); ?> >

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );

    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

    $thumbnail_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );

    // Calculate aspect ratio: h / w * 100%.
    $ratio = $thumbnail_attributes[2] / $thumbnail_attributes[1] * 100;
    ?>

    <div class="panel-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>);">
        <div class="panel-image-prop" style="padding-top: <?php echo esc_attr( $ratio ); ?>%"></div>

    </div><!-- .panel-image -->

<?php endif; ?>

<div class="panel-content">
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
                the_content( sprintf(
                    __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentyseventeen' ),
                    get_the_title()
                ) );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    </div><!-- .wrap -->
</div><!-- .panel-content -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

My additional code is below. What I'm trying to achieve right now is to pull 3 recent posts with the post title placed over the post's featured image. I haven't completed the CSS, that's something I'll work on by myself after I can call those 3 posts to the page.

```
<div class="row featured-posts-box">
  <ul class="top-featured-image">
<?php
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>'3',));
    while($recentPosts->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
?>
<li class="post-thumbnail">
        <span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' ); ?>
        </a></span>
    </li><!-- .post-thumbnail -->
<?php
endwhile;
?>
</ul>
```

The code above keeps breaking my site. I think it's the `while` loop, but I'm not sure.

I don't want to use a plugin. I actually want to learn how to develop a wordpress theme.

Comment: What does it mean "keeps breaking my site"?

Comment: you should reset post data after finishing loop. `use wp_reset_postdata();` right after `endwhile;` . and also `while($recentPosts->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ` line should be `while($recentPosts->have_posts()): $recentPosts->the_post(); `

Comment: @SabbirHasan: if I could upvote you, I would.   thank you so much.  The post title being on top of the image, can be achieved through css?  I'll just try getting the look that I want try on my own and if I have any questions, I'll look through the archives before posting another question.  :)

Comment: check my answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for you CSS issue.
yes you can achieve that layout using CSS. Just follow this structure:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="image"><img src=""/></div>
  <div class = "overlay"> Add you title here </div>
</div>
```

here .parent must me **position:relative**  and .overlay must be **position:absolute** with **100%width** and **bottom:0** . you can play around with style.